# Setting/changing min SDK and Target SDK versions in code

Tags: android

is it possible to set the Minumum SDK and target SDK versions in code for an Android Application? Normally this is specified in the Manifest.xml file

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 4):

No it is not, the system should be able to read it before it runs your application.

> When preparing to install your application, the system checks the
>   value of this attribute and compares it to the system version. If the
>   **android:minSdkVersion** value is greater than the system version, the
>   system aborts the installation of the application. Similarly, the
>   system installs your application only if its **android:maxSdkVersion** is
>   compatible with the platform version.
>
> If you do not specify these attributes in your manifest, the system
>   assumes that your application is compatible with all platform
>   versions, with no maximum API Level.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible. This information is used in determining if your application can even run on a particular device based on the OS. How can you run an application and then determine if it is ok based on the OS.